# HTML not loading external css

Tags: html, css

This html isn't getting any of the css. Any help on what I am missing - thanks.

#### fun.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="mainsite.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Hyper Text Markup Language," />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Miguel Castaneda" />
    <meta name="robots" content="all, nofollow" />
    <title>Building Blocks to Html</title>
</head>

    <body>
    <p class="center">THis class was center</p>
    <p id="center">This id was centered</p>
    <h1>This is h1 text</h1>

        </body> 


</html>
```

#### mainsite.css

```
#nav{
    //position: fixed;
    /right: 200px;
    //top: 200px;
    }

.center{
     text-align:center;
     color:red;

     }

center{
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
    }

body{color:blue;}


h1 {color:#00ff00;}
```

Comment: Are you certain the stylesheet is being *loaded*?  If not, view source.  In modern browsers, when you view source, you can then often *click on* the stylesheet href, which will try to load it.  If you get a 404, then you know that it isn't loading for some reason.

Comment: Don't know if its a typo in ur post but u have a single / in #nav which would break ur css

Comment: Also try and put the link after ur meta tags

Comment: Also useful is to use the "network" tab in your browser's developer tools to see exactly what is loaded and when.

Comment: Are you sure, both files are in the same folder?

Comment: Sten, Another way to find out if your stylesheet is loading as @Cale already stated, is to inspect the page with Chrome Inspector and click on Console. You will get a 404 list there showing the bad connections to any page from your page including Jqueries and css not loading

Comment: I wet to my fun.html page then right click inspect element then console nothing happened, I reloaded the page again and nothing came up on the console

Comment: yes they are in the same folder im not sure what i did right now but the css worked and centered the <p> and colored the text thank you. ill try and see what I did to post the anwser

Comment: Note that you will want `#center` to style the `p` with id center.

Answer (score 0):

i think that's the correct way to link css file, try it...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file.css"/>
```

Make sure both files are in the same folder since you didn't enter a path for your css

also your html file is missing the opening of codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

Comment: The missing HTML was a code-formatting error, which I just fixed; much of the code block was not formatted for the MD processor to render it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your CSS since you have 'center' listed twice and therefore your mainsite.css file is not being loaded properly.  Just delete the second 'center' id.

CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */

#nav{
  //position: fixed;
 /right: 200px;
//top: 200px;
    }

.center{
 text-align:center;
  color:red;

     }

body{color:blue;}


 h1 {color:#00ff00;}
```

Comment: I doubt this is the case... two different selectors, one for a center class, the other for a center element. This should not "break" the CSS

Comment: Just realized that now lol  Originally it wasn't loading for me but I think it might have been a file naming issue.  The CSS loads fine for me on my end.

Answer (score 0):

check the path or clean the cache